# calculating memory consumed by each file extensions in python

Tags: python, file, storage

I am trying calculate the space consumed by each file extensions in the different directories as well as the file extensions and their count.
I was able to retrieve the all file extensions and their count by the following code:

```
import os
def count_all_ext ( path ):
    res = {}
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ):
        for f in files :
            if '.' in f :
                e = f.rsplit('.',1)[1]
                res[e] = res.setdefault(e,0)+1
    return res.items()
op= '\n'.join( '%s:%d'%i for i in count_all_ext('/home'))
```

Output of the following is:

```
baseB:4
code:100
cache-6:55
Xauthority:1
baseA:4
npmrc:1
apmrc:1
gz:186
dbf:1
lst:2
markdown:10
sqlite-shm:2
vsixmanifest:4
ttf:109
pkl:31
gitignore:8
xml:46
22:1
la:9
sublime-keymap:1
cache:103
jar:1
ts:704
desktop:3
source:1
sqlite3-journal:1
TAG:1
4:1
usage:6
oTN4k5:1
bin:6
docx:9
rb:1
woff:3
db:17
gpg-agent:1
V2XO5Y:1
dat:3
fingerprint:4
lz4:1
converted-launchers:1
bat:5
bau:1
pset:42
name:2
crt:8
dll:42
h:122
cmd:2
list:2
xlb:2
dic:1
zsh-update:1
editorconfig:4
stderr:8
sublime_session:1
xls:1
bak:1
bond:108
node:16
56:3
old:26
babelrc:2
locale:1
cfg:3
htm:1
odt:1
keyring:1
gypi:1
meta:2
md~:1
pma:2
sqlite-journal:1
odb:2
patch:2
todo:1
tvc:1
out:20
tmp:4
ps1:8
stats:6
icc:1
zprofile:1
dbt:1
re:21
3:1
mozlz4:2
7:9
ics:3
spec:9
sys:1
reg:3
metadata:6
dirs:1
whl:2
run:1
asar:1
jsonlz4:14
tdb:4
journal:2
zshrc:1
gradle:3
little:2
pub:1
js:4336
asc:1
git:1
key:12
xbel:1
properties:2
bash:1
eslintignore:1
c:283
zip:6
idx:5
lsup7I:1
zcompdump:1
un~:2
vbs:1
base:1
dmrc:1
Mdg80A:1
sbstore:42
pdf:18
tmLanguage:11
xlc:2
py:483
tgz:2
gitkeep:2
iml:2
xz:1
bashrc:1
db-journal:3
pf2:5
localstorage:95
yaml:8
tmPreferences:4
isrunning:1
txt:287
orig:2
gvdb:1
xpi:9
php:12
gitmodules:1
log:49
swo:1
jshintrc:6
stamp:2
vxd:1
fmt:1
1vCfy0:1
sock:2
pb:32
gif:3
json:2128
2:2
js-20170612122310:1
prl:9
swp:2
bash_logout:1
final:1
pl:1
exe:21
a:2
sdv:1
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu:1
parentlock:2
cson:8
rcache:2
6:1
otf:29
sublime-settings:1
xinputrc:1
gitconfig:1
npmignore:84
localstorage-journal:95
gyp:1
rst:11
update-timestamp:1
bnf:1
png:2340
db-shm:1
info:1
md:844
js-20170816210634:1
sublime-snippet:14
tsv:1
gpg:1
sth:19
mk:5
yml:47
sqlite-wal:2
ino:1
pem:4
deb:3
zsh:235
pack:5
zsh_history:1
sqlite:24
tar:1
stdout:8
jscsrc:1
lock:3
pro:1
DB:4
coffee:8
jpg:23
jamignore:1
sample:72
watchr:1
jshintignore:1
ini:14
conf:17
xcu:1
sudo_as_admin_successful:1
plist:1
xsession-errors:1
keystore:1
nls:1
bdic:1
0:11
1:8
html:89
5:10
MZPZ5Y:1
sqlite3:1
pak:61
config:1
css:112
```

So i want the output in the form:

```
file extension:<totalsize consumed>
.
.
.
```

How to find the file extension and space consumed by each extensions by manipulating the above code.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I am able to retrieve the values for particular extensions but unable to achieve the same for all the extensions!!.So seeking help as beginner

Comment: Try replacing your file extension count `+1` with `os.stat(path).st_size`. Go read/skim the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html) and [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html) module pages so you can learn about methods like `os.path.splitext(path)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to look into os.stat, this method will allow you to read the file size in bytes. If you would like it in other size like megabytes, you will need to do some conversions between the two.

Here is something to get you started:

```
import os
def count_all_ext ( path ):
    res = {}
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ):
        for f in files :
            if '.' in f :
                statinfo = os.stat(os.path.join(root,f))
                e = f.rsplit('.',1)[1]
                res.setdefault(e,[]).append((statinfo.st_size))
    return res.items()
op= '\n'.join( '{}:{}'.format(key, array) for key,array in count_all_ext(r'C:\Users\user\.anaconda\navigator'))
print(op)
```

Reference material for [os.stat](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_stat.htm)

Comment: Nice answer! Also, please use os.path.splitext instead of f.rsplit

Comment: @Sjn73 sum(array) will work when you print the value, or just keep a running sum when you track the files

Comment: @WilliamFlores: yeah used sum( ) method, Thanks for the help!